# JNI GetByteArrayElements causes SIGSEGV while getting bytes from object field

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am trying to pass data from JAVA to C++ using an utilitary class with a couple of fields. One of them is a byte array.

I am having a hard time trying to get the byte array field from an jobject in JNI. I can get the object and Field ID correctly but I cannot get the jbyteArray. My code causes a SIGSEGV signal.

This is the Java class that I pass to the native call:

```
public class T011Data {
    public char chTransRes;
    public byte[] btFormat;
}
```

This is the native fuction call:

```
T011Data data = new T011Data();     
data.chTransRes = 12;
data.btFormat = new byte[]{0x20,0x21,0x22,0x23,0x24};
PrkPxy.SerializeT011(data);
```

This is my C++ implementation

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_javax_pos_prk_PrkPxy_SerializeT011(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jobject jobT011Data){
    T011Data srCmdData;
    srCmdData.chTransResult = chGetCharField(env,jobT011Data,"chTransRes");
    srCmdData.inFormatLen = inGetByteArrayField(env,jobT011Data,"btFormat",srCmdData.pchFormat);
    delete srCmdData.pchFormat;
}
```

And this is an utilitary function to extract a byte array field from an object. It is causing a SIGSEGV:

```
int inGetByteArrayField(JNIEnv * env, jobject jobData, char * pchFieldID, char * pchOutput){
    jclass jcClass = env->GetObjectClass(jobData);
    jfieldID jfArrayId = env->GetFieldID(jcClass, pchFieldID, "[B");

    jobject jobArray = env->GetObjectField(jcClass, jfArrayId);

    jbyteArray * arr = reinterpret_cast<jbyteArray *>(&jobArray);


    //This line is causing a SIGSEGV!!!
    char * pchData = (char *)env->GetByteArrayElements(*arr, NULL);



    int inArrayLen = env->GetArrayLength(*arr);

    pchOutput = new char[inArrayLen];

    memcpy(pchOutput,pchData,inArrayLen);

    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(*arr, (jbyte *) pchData, 0);

    return inArrayLen; 
}
```

I checked the field id value and it is non-zero.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It turns out the line jobject jobArray = env->GetObjectField(jcClass, jfArrayId); is wrong: I should pass jobData as first parameter instead of jcClass.

Comment: Yep, [NativeType Get<type>Field(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jfieldID fieldID);](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) pretty much says it. Does your IDE have function signature tips or equiv? Also with proper error handling, JNI library functions should not fault since you would avoid passing in invalid parameters.